# Is $\lim_{s \to \infty} \int f(x) g(s)dx$ equal to $\int f(x) (\lim_{s \to \infty}g(s) ) dx$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{s \to \infty} \int f(x) g(s)dx = \int f(x) (\lim_{s \to \infty}g(s) ) dx$$

Is this equality true? Can you move the limit operator inside of the integral, since we're not integrating with respect to the variable in the limit?

Comment: You can pull $g(s)$ outside the integral, and then the scalar $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ outside the limit. (I assume you mean a definite integral, otherwise how are you defining the limit?)

Comment: Sure, assuming the limit exists. You could also just pull $g(s)$ out of the integral and perform the limit on the outside since $g(s)$ does not depend on the variable of integration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if the limit exists and $F$ is integrable. $\int f(x)g(s)dx=g(s)\int f(x)dx$  the limit is $(\lim g(s)) \int f(x)dx$